# Does adding firebase plugins affects the way "flutter run" behaves?

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, dart, flutter-run

I created a flutter project and worked on it for a while and the compile time (`flutter run`) was okay but when I needed to use Firebase plugins the compile time was very slow, that is, I added the required dependencies from Firebase console to my android Gradle file and it became slower.

why is that? And are there ways to improve the compile time?